# android app cannot connect to twitter

Tags: android, twitter

My android application uses jtwitter and doesn't see api.twitter.com host

```
    Twitter twitter = new Twitter("user", "pass");
    System.out.println(twitter.getStatus("somebody"));
    twitter.setStatus("my stat");
```

But java desktop application works pretty good. What is the problem can be with android? I added even uses-permission INTERNET

Comment: Are you getting something in the logs? check `adb shell logcat`

Answer (score 1):

Igor read this :: [Twitter finally deciding to deprecate the existing Basic Authentication by June 2010](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq)

now you must use [Twitter OAuth for Android](http://blog.sogeti.com/mobile/2010/03/twitter-oauth-for-android.html)

this is a very good and useful example:: [How to use SignPost and Twitter4J with OAuth](http://code.google.com/p/agirardello/)

Jorgesys